# WideImage PHP plugin wrong resize height

Tags: php, plugins

I'm using this PHP plugin for image manipulation: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

This is my code:

```
WideImage::load('images/image_test.jpg')

-> resize(300, 150)
-> output('jpg');
```

And this is the result:

[image]

If you look at the dimensions of the screenshot, you'll see they do not coincide with what I told the dimensions to be.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like it tries to maintain the aspect ratio (height / width). You probably don't want to get your images flattened or stretched, but there should be a setting for this. Maybe setting the `$fit` parameter to "fill" will help: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_Image.html#methodresize

LE: On the other hand, perhaps you should consider [cropping](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_Image.html#methodcrop), if you want to change the image size, without altering its aspect.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks. I'll paste the corrected code as an answer. I already crop, this is just a small part of the function that gave me a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer (thanks to Mihai Todor):

```
WideImage::load('images/image_test.jpg')

-> resize(300, 150, 'fill')
-> output('jpg');
```

Apparently it needed the fill statement.